# MySQL missing data base

Tags: mysql

After exporting my data base in MySQL I can not locate the data base on my original workbench,but my application is running well. My problem is I can't effect any change to my work. How do I recover my data base in MySQL workbench?

Comment: Exporting should have any effect on the original database, it just makes a snapshot of it in a file.

Comment: Maybe you're connecting to the wrong instance, or as the wrong user? In any case this isn't a programming-specific question.